# In Stephen Baxter's "Xeelee: Redemption" is this reference to a ship an error?

Tags: xeelee-sequence

In chapter 16 of *Xeelee: Redemption*, there is a reference to the *Cauchy*, which I believe should read *Island*.

Am I correct about this?

> **16**
>
> After the first month on Ghost Plateau, as Susan Chen called it - a month the ***Cauchy*** crew spent mostly securing their physical survival - Chen said she had a proposal for them.
>
> 'You know that we work for the Ghosts, down on the planet.  I mean, in the Xeelee Valleys.  Where the Xeelee buildings grow.'
>
> Nicola grinned '*Where the Xeelee buildings grow*. Susan, what a line!'
>
> Susan's own smile, like all her expressions, was a sketch.  'We - I mean, my crewmates, my charges - they have us seek Xeelee artifacts.  Now the Ghosts intend to send a party down, to retrieve what we have collected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does indeed appear to be an error.  In chapter 15 it is clear that it is the *Island* that lands:

> After the *Island*'s lifedome was set down on rocky ground, close to the other ship, a Ghost came.  Hovered just outside the dome.
>
> When Jophiel was informed, he hurried that way - hurried, though his Virtual projection software faithfully transmitted to him the burden of this world's forty per cent higher gravity.  Nicola, Asher and Harris followed him more cautiously, Harris with a medical pack slung over his shoulder.

While the *Cauchy* remains at a distance:

> He glanced back at the *Island* lifedome, a shell of light.  Many of the crew were crowded close to the wall, watching them go.
>
> And he noticed the wormhole interface, an electric-blue tetrahedron still intact on top of the dome.
>
> He looked away.  If the Ghosts had yet to puzzle out that feature, and its significance - the only link to the *Cauchy*, the only possible source of any help - he didn't want to draw their attention to it.

In chapter 17, it is once again the *Island*:

> The *Island* crew listened to this, electrified.

(Note that "the *Island* crew" in question is Jophiel, Nicola and Harris Kemp, the same characters as in the previous 2 chapters.)